# Windows Phone 7 : Control the phone from the computer

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, mobile

It seems that in every demo I see of developing for the Windows Phone 7 platform, they show the device screen on the computer screen.

What do they use to do that ?  While developing, I would like ton control my device from my computer...  and using the keyboard for testing the device, not the emulator.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not correct. Hit Pause/Break to use your computer keyboard instead of the emulator keyboard. More key commands outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754352%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: @Jac: You've changed my life.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft employees have access to a special build of the phone OS which permits them to plug the phone into a projecter.  You cannot get a copy of the same OS, so you cannot show the phone screen on your computer.

You can debug and test you code on a phone however.  Then you can access the music hub, test the hardware and sensors.  To do this you need to create a developer account and unlock your phone. [Getting started with the phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

You must unlock your phone via your AppHub account ([create.msdn.com](http://create.msdn.com)) to enable sideloading of apps onto the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a web service (WCF would be the easiest since you are building interactions with a .NET app) and send commands from a client PC to the service and the app (WP7) will read the data via the service (e.g. the service can push values to the device). You probably won't be able to get total control of the system at this point, since the API doesn't give developers low level access to input hooks, but if the application is your own, all you need is a presentation layer on top of it.